# How to handle the number of views

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity Agence which has an attribute **nbView**, I'd like to increment **nbView + 1** when a visitor view profile of agence. but right now if the same visitor refreshes the page, nbView will always incremented + 1 and this is not a good behavior.

```
public function viewAction(Agence $agence, $slug, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //.......
    $agence = $em->getRepository('ProjectAgenceBundle:Agence')->findOneBySlug($slug);

    // incrempent nbView
    $agence->setNbView($agence->getNbView() + 1);
    $em->persist($agence) ;
    $em->flush() ;

    //.................
    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Agence:agence-detail-view.html.twig',
    array(
        'agence' => $agence,
        'travel' => $travel,
        'contact_agence_form' => $form_contact->createView(),
    ));
}
```

what is the right way to do that ?

Comment: You could use session, cookies and/or ip log ?

Comment: that means I have to create an entity NnbView and save  sessions and time of visit .... ?

Comment: I would personally just use cookies

Comment: I don't know how to use cookies in this case :/ but I'll search how to do it

Answer (score 0):

As a way you can add additional entity UserViewedAgence
(id,
user_id,
user_agence_id)
Before update the viewed agence counter you have to check if user has already viewed the agence